# How to parse JSON in Android?

Tags: android, json

I am try to develop a sample application for YouTube to play video on my android device directly from YouTube. In this respect I have developed some code to parse JSON, but I haven't succeeded so far. Please help me, how to parse Youtube JSON?
Here is my code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getVideoJSON ();
    }

    public JSONObject getVideoJSON () 
    {
        final String URL = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/Football/uploads?v=2&alt=json";

        try
        {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); 
            String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            JSONArray VideoData = new JSONArray(data);
            JSONObject video = VideoData.getJSONObject(0); 


            Log.e("URL", "Successfully parse");

            return video;


        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("URL", "Failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This url is returning to you a JSONObject, not a JSONArray, try this:

```
public JSONObject getVideoJSON () 
    {
        final String URL = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/Football/uploads?v=2&alt=json";

        try
        {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); 
            String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            JSONObject VideoData = new JSONObject(data); 


            Log.e("URL", "Successfully parse");

            return video;


        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("URL", "Failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }
```

If you want to see your JSON structure more clearly, this site can be helpful: http://json-indent.appspot.com/